# How can I count the number of occurrences of multiple intersections in a nested list

Tags: python, set, python-itertools, nested-lists

UPDATED QUESTION:
I have a number of nested lists similar to this one:

```
l = [['y', 'ha', 'ua', 'uk'], ['o', 'j', 'sb', 'ku'], 
['j', 'c', 'ts', 'ar'], ['nec', 'hv', 'f', 'uf'], 
['y', 'nec', 'fs', 'ks']]
```

Each list is a group of people and each sublist is one person's characteristics.  I want to count the number of people with overlapping characteristics.

I created a counter dictionary to find all of the results > 1.

```
dups = dict((k, v) for k, v in dups.items() if (v >= 2))
#{'y': 2, 'j': 2, 'nec': 2}
```

If I add the values of dups together, I get 6 when there are only 5 sublists.  I need to find all of the sublists with more than one overlapping value.

In other words, my question is how can I get 5 (since all 5 sublists have at least 1 value in common).

I tried creating the combinations as follows:

```
import itertools    
characteristics = list(dups.keys())
set_c = set(characteristics)
combos = list(itertools.combinations(set_c, 2))
sub_list = list(combos)
sub_list2 = [list(x) for x in sub_list]
print(sub_list2)
#[['nec', 'y'], ['nec', 'j'], ['y', 'j']]
```

I tried the code below, but it has problems (like it doesn't count multiple Booleans):

```
counter = 0
if (all(x for y in l for x in sub_list2)):
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
else:
    print("No, list is not subset of other.")
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? If you have two lists with a value `a` and another two lists with a value `b`, is the answer 2 or 4?

Comment: 4.  The result eventually gets divided by the total number in even more lists to calculate the % of overlaps.  The data comes from (parts of) a csv file.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on the requirement, but this may be what you're looking for:

```
l = [['y', 'ha', 'ua', 'uk'], 
     ['o', 'j', 'sb', 'ku'], 
     ['j', 'c', 'ts', 'ar'], 
     ['nec', 'hv', 'f', 'uf'], 
     ['y', 'nec', 'fs', 'ks']]
     
# get all keys 
all = set()

for l2 in l:
   all |= set(l2)  # merge elements, remove duplicates

d = {k:0 for k in all}  # dictionary for counts
for l1 in l:
   for e in l1:
       d[e] += 1

t = [(k,d[k]) for k in d if d[k] > 1] # remove count = 1

print(t)
```

Output

```
[('j', 2), ('nec', 2), ('y', 2)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what I'm looking for.  Here's a different approach to my question.